# Returning polymorphic types with GADTs in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Take the following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE DataKinds, GADTs #-}


module Lib where

import System.Random as Randy

someFunc :: IO ()
someFunc = dataKinds >>= \n -> putStrLn (show n)

data Kind a where
  IntK :: Int -> Kind Int
  StringK :: String -> Kind String
  BoolK :: Bool -> Kind Bool
  OtherK :: a -> Kind a


instance Show (Kind a) where
  show (IntK n)    = "KindInt " ++ show n
  show (StringK s) = "KindString " ++ s
  show (BoolK b)   = "KindBool " ++ show b


dataKinds :: IO (Kind a)
dataKinds =
  Randy.getStdRandom (Randy.randomR (1,6)) >>= \n ->
    case n of
       1 -> pure $ IntK n
       2 -> pure $ IntK n
       3 -> pure $ StringK (show n)
       4 -> pure $ StringK (show n)
       5 -> pure $ BoolK True
       6 -> pure $ BoolK False
```

This code will not compile, basically because the compiler doesn't like the fact that the `pure $ IntK n` specifies that `Kind Int` is returned by the first line, but `StringK` and `BoolK` are returned by the last four lines:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Int’
  Expected type: IO (Kind Int)    
    Actual type: IO (Kind String)                               
• In the expression: pure $ StringK (show n)
```

This strikes me as odd. I can do this easily without GADTs, just using the normal `data` declaration. But I had assumed that an enhancement like GADTs would not reduce the flexibility of the type system but add to it. Am I doing something wrong? I've only just encountered this extension so it's possible I've misunderstood something. How can I make the program compile using GADTs?

Comment: How would you do this without a GADT?

Comment: `data Kind a = IntK Int | StringK String | BoolK Bool` etc. And then just use `dataKinds :: IO Kind a` as above.

Comment: That's not the same. In this declaration all constructors construct values of the same type, but in your GADT declaration constructors construct values of different types.

Comment: That corresponds to `... where IntK :: Int -> Kind a; StringK :: String -> Kind a; ...` in GADT syntax.

Comment: Incidentally, you can do a little factoring: `case n of { 1 -> pure $ …; 2 -> pure $ …; 3 -> pure $ …; … }` can be written `pure $ case n of { 1 -> …; 2 -> …; 3 -> …; … }`.

Comment: melopmene: That is actually the correct answer to this problem! Thanks for that, and also thanks to Fyodor who explained why it's the correct answer!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make the type `xx` of `Kind xx` existential (does not appear in return type)

```
data SomeKind where
  SomeKind :: Kind xx -> SomeKind

-- Only works because of: instance           Show (Kind a)
-- Would not work with:   instance Show a => Show (Kind a)
instance Show SomeKind where
  show :: SomeKind -> String
  show (SomeKind kind) = show kind
```

And implement `dataKinds :: IO SomeKind`.

---

(Implement `dataKinds` with an `fmap`)

(Extract `Kind` out of `SomeKind`, can we write a `Show` instance?)

```
data Some :: (k -> Type) -> Type where
  Some :: f xx -> Some f

instance ??? => Show (Some f) where
  show :: Some f -> String
  show (Some some) = show some
```

Comment: The existential wrapper worked, thanks! I suppose I'm pointlessly criticising the language itself now, but you'd think that the above code would work without the wrapper.

Comment: Richard Eisenberg (who has been working on `-XDependentTypes` for GHC) comments on future work: [“A key step along this path is lightweight existentials, allowing you do use `exists x. ...` in a type as easily as `forall x. ...`.”](https://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/4amov2/the_future_of_dependent_haskell/d14xtjs/?context=3) so maybe in the future we can write `IO (exists xx. Kind xx)`.

Answer (score 3):

You might need an existential wrapper, e.g.

```
data SomeKind where
   SomeKind :: Kind a -> SomeKind

dataKinds :: IO SomeKind
dataKinds =
  Randy.getStdRandom (Randy.randomR (1,6)) >>= \n ->
    case n of
       1 -> pure . SomeKind $ IntK n
       2 -> pure . SomeKind $ IntK n
       3 -> pure . SomeKind $ StringK (show n)
       4 -> pure . SomeKind $ StringK (show n)
       5 -> pure . SomeKind $ BoolK True
       6 -> pure . SomeKind $ BoolK False
```